# Limit ForeignKey models by count

Tags: python, django, count, foreign-keys

This is my model and I want to limit the number of photos that a user can upload just 10. I want to do it one place so it works in the admin and user facing forms. Can someone help me out here?

```
class StarPhotos(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    PHOTO_CATEGORY = (
    ('HS', "Head Shot"),
    ('WP', "Western Party Wear"),
    ('IP', "Indian Party Wear"),
    ('SW', "Swim Wear"),
    ('CW', "Casual Wear"),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PHOTO_CATEGORY, default='CW')
# This FileField should preferaby be changed to ImageField with pillow installed.
    photos = models.FileField(max_length=200, upload_to='images/',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Images for {0}".format(self.user)
```

Comment: you can use a check function that will check how much photos a user have uploaded so far. Although i think there may be a better solution

Comment: I suggest you to override `create()` and `save()` depending upon usage to check the item count before the items are created.

Comment: usually save() will not be called in admin since it uses bulk_create()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a checker function in your model to check whether User has uploaded 10 photos or not

```
def check_photo_count(self, user):
    photo_count = self.object.filter(user=user).count()
    return photo_count
```

This does not seem to be the best solution available but it should work.
Also remember to put a check for this in your views or admin. You can also return a Boolean value from this function saying that this user is allowed to upload more photos or not.

This same logic can be applied to [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects) if you don't want to put checks everywhere.

So you just have to put this check in the create method and if the check fails simply raise a error or return a false value saying that object is not created.

Comment: Thanks Arpit but doing that I'll have to add code to everywhere a form is shown. @Muhammad Fahad Manzoor is there a snippet of code I can see that helps me understand how it's done?

Comment: @chewinggumking Updated the answer. Checkout the link that how to use Model Managers.

Comment: Thanks for your really quick reply bhai. But I might need a bit more handholding than that. I've looked at that page in the docs before almost till I went crosseyed and just couldn't understand how to make it do what I want. If you can help me nothing like it or if you can't but know a model on github or somewhere else that you might have seen something like that I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can override save and bulk_create methods from StarPhotos, I don't check the code, but it's some like that:

```
class CheckPhotoModelManager(models.Manager):
    def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None):
        photos = StarPhotos.object.filter(user=objs[0].user).count()
        if photos < 10:
            super(StarPhotos, self).bulk_create(...)

class StarPhotos(models.Model):
   objects = CheckPhotoModelManager()
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       photos = StarPhotos.object.filter(user=self.user).count()
       if photos < 10:
            super(StarPhotos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```